# Insert image in database using fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I am trying to send my image into database using fragments.Initially the code below was working well with activity but when I used fragments it is not creating database instead a new folder app_downloads is created in which my images are being saved in png format.The code tgat I have tried is-

```
    public class MainFragment extends Activity {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
            //ButtonFragment buttonfrag=new ButtonFragment();
            //NumericFragment numericfrag=new NumericFragment();
            CaptureSignature capture=new CaptureSignature();
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            //transaction.add(R.id.buttonframelayout,buttonfrag,"button");
            transaction.add(R.id.emailframelayout,capture,"button");
            transaction.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_fragment, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }

public class CaptureSignature extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
 LinearLayout mContent;
    signature mSignature;
    Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
    public static String tempDir;
    public int count = 1;
    public String current = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    View mView;
    File mypath;
    Context context;

    private String uniqueId;
    private EditText yourName;
    public DatabaseMethods db;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    db=new DatabaseMethods(getActivity());
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View viewFrag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signature, container, false);
     //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     // DatabaseMethods db=new DatabaseMethods(this);
     tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
     ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());
     File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     prepareDirectory();
     uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_" + Math.random();
     current = uniqueId + ".png";
     mypath= new File(directory,current);
     Log.e("path"," "+mypath);
     mContent = (LinearLayout)viewFrag. findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
     mSignature = new signature(getActivity(), null);
     mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
     mClear = (Button)viewFrag.findViewById(R.id.clear);
     mGetSign = (Button)viewFrag.findViewById(R.id.getsign);
     mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
     mCancel = (Button)viewFrag.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
     mView = mContent;
     yourName = (EditText)viewFrag.findViewById(R.id.yourName);

        mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {       
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
                mSignature.clear();
                mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {       
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
                boolean error = captureSignature();
                if(!error){
                    mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    mSignature.save(mView);
                    /*Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("status", "done");
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);  
                    finish();*/
                }
            }
        });

        mCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {       
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
                /*Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("status", "cancel");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                finish();*/
            }
        });
    return viewFrag;
    }

   /* @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.w("GetSignature", "onDestory");
        super.onDestroy();
    }*/

    private boolean captureSignature() {

        boolean error = false;
        String errorMessage = "";


        if(yourName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            errorMessage = errorMessage + "Please enter your Name\n";
            error = true;
        }  

        if(error){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 105, 50);
            toast.show();
        }

        return error;
    }

    private String getTodaysDate() {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int todaysDate =     (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000) +
        ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100) +
        (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Log.w("DATE:",String.valueOf(todaysDate));
        return(String.valueOf(todaysDate));

    }

    private String getCurrentTime() {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentTime =     (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 10000) +
        (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 100) +
        (c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        Log.w("TIME:",String.valueOf(currentTime));
        return(String.valueOf(currentTime));

    }


    private boolean prepareDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            if (makedirs())
            {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", 1000).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean makedirs()
    {
        File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
        if (!tempdir.exists())
            tempdir.mkdirs();

        if (tempdir.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files)
            {
                if (!file.delete())
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
                }
            }
        }
        return (tempdir.isDirectory());
    }

    public class signature extends View
    {
        private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
        private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();
        Context context;

        private float lastTouchX;
        private float lastTouchY;
        private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

        public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        }

        public void save(View v)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
            Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
            if(mBitmap == null)
            {
                mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
            }
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
                v.draw(canvas);
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
                mFileOutStream.flush();
                mFileOutStream.close();
                String url = Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
                Log.v("log_tag","url: " + url);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,baos);
                byte[] byteData=baos.toByteArray();
                db.open();
                db.storeImage(byteData);
                //In case you want to delete the file
                //boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
                //Log.v("log_tag","deleted: " + mypath.toString() + deleted);
                //If you want to convert the image to string use base64 converter

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
            }
        }

        public void clear()
        {
            path.reset();
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++)
                {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;

            default:
                debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                return false;
            }

            invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;

            return true;
        }

        private void debug(String string){
        }

        private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY)
        {
            if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left)
            {
                dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
            }
            else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right)
            {
                dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
            }

            if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top)
            {
                dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
            }
            else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom)
            {
                dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
            }
        }

        private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY)
        {
            dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
            dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

How can I send my images into database?

Comment: Have you got any exception??

Comment: @PiyushGupta: no there was no exception

Comment: How? what was the issue?

Comment: My DatabaseMethod class was not being invoked anf there we some other problems too i will paste the new code in some time..

Comment: Okay That's really great.

Comment: replace this line                 String url = Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
 with                 String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null); and 
create object of database class before onCreate method.